# calculating a good initial temperature for simulated annealing

Tags: algorithm, performance, heuristics, traveling-salesman, simulated-annealing

I've done some testing of different initial temperatures in my simulating annealing algorithm and noticed the starting temperature has an affect on the performance of the algorithm.

Is there any way of calculating a good initial temperature?

Comment: If you are scared of advanced math: no. Else: see [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11126/initial-temperature-in-simulated-annealing-algorithm).